# How do count the number of cells that contain a substring in a given array?

Tags: excel

I have hundreds of cells that contain sentences in them.  I want to be able to search each one to see if it matches something that I have provided it in an array.

For example

Column A
"The dog runs fast"
"The cat runs fast"
"The human runs fast"
"The dog is a human"

How can I search through each of the 4 cells above to check to see if the cell contains either "dog" or "human."  The answer should be 3 since in the 4th cell dog and human should only count once.

Thanks ahead.  I can do it in SQL, but not in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to enter the following formula in B2 (assuming header row exists), and fill down column B:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FIND("dog",A2),0),IFERROR(FIND("human",A2),0)) > 0
```

And then `=COUNTIF(B:B, TRUE)`.

Comment: It's returning false for everything when i try it.  I also tried it with wildcards  "*dog*"  and "*human*"

Comment: @LeythG - apologies, should have referred to column A in the `find`. Edited.